# What HID/Module does Air mouse use in Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, linux-mint, linux-kernel

I was thinking about developing a module for running a Air Mouse.
I am not sure as what module s used to carry out the operation done by air mouse. Is it under HID?
(I am talking about a wireless Air mouse so probably carries out interaction via sockets.)

Comment: Which device exactly are you referring to? Please name the make and model.

Comment: I was looking for a general set of modules, For example this device
http://www.gearbest.com/mice-keyboards/pp_23727.html?currency=USD&gclid=CjgKEAjwq_qcBRDZ-PeZ7NGQiVwSJAATT7q242A1vdUCLwCMAsvM4NUKb3OaPfVxbW1jNVfUy5nUR_D_BwE

Comment: It is extremely unlikely they all work the same way. That being said, there’s probably no need for a driver at all. Just poke around with the HID RAW driver. As for gesture detection, be warned: This is very hard to accomplish.